# keep kmail folders on external hard drive

Tags: kubuntu, kde, email, kmail

I have limited space on my local hard drive. With thunderbird I can easily keep all my mail on a folder on an external hard drive by moving the thunderbird profile folder to the external disk and creating a symbolic link to it on my home folder. This also allows me to use the exact same profile folder when I boot to different linux versions (e.g. different versions of Kubuntu on the same or a different computer). Is there a way to do the same with kmail? My e-mail accounts are all IMAP, but I want to keep a copy (on the external hard drive) of all the e-mail I have in case I'm disconnected from the internet.